# how to use layouts to show and change images?

Tags: android, image

hi ive asked this question a few times each time trying something new in my code but have failed to get this to work.
[how can i handle images and change there function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555311/how-can-i-handle-images-and-change-there-function)

it explains quite well what i want to achieve but basically id like a bunch of imageViews/buttons on the bottom and when each button is clicked it should go to the top and change the images in the bottom affectively creating some kind of image keyboard.

the resulting code should essentially allow a user to create sentences using images. ive looked at gridView and gridLayout and updating them with arrays but with no joy can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: not clear ur prob but u can use a parent and iterate with its child count to perform opearations..

Comment: @Manmohan thanks for your advice but I'm really new to android any chance you could elaborate?

Comment: as i told earlier i also confused. if u have any sample which u can provide then u can share ur problem more or than i'll tell u how to do such.

Comment: @Manmohan sorry have you checked the link I gave? It has screen shots of how the activity runs at the moment and my code